# Dynamic Dropdown not working in GSP

Tags: java, jsp, grails, drop-down-menu, gsp

In my view page my HTML is following-

```
<select id="sereousness" >
<option value="0" ${(subscribed.sereousness == '0')?'selected':''}>Casual${subscribed.sereousness}</option>
<option value="1" ${(subscribed.sereousness == '1')?'selected':''}>Sereous${subscribed.sereousness}</option>
<option value="2"  ${(subscribed.sereousness == '2')?'selected':''}>VerySereous${subscribed.sereousness}</option>
</select>
```

but this is displaying first option as selected every time even value of `${subscribed.sereousness}` is different?

[image]

Comment: How is defined `subscribed.sereousness`?

Comment: Look at the HTML that is generated, what does it say? Where is the 'selected' tag?

Comment: `subscribed` is object of class TrendingTopicCO {

    int sereousness

}

Comment: Try to output the value in the html inside a tag like `<p>${(subscribed.sereousness}</p>`, then post here the generated html, including the select/option part.

Comment: you should not compare int's with Strings: `(subscribed.sereousness == 0)?'selected':''`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to build your SELECT is to use Grail's [g:select](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html) tag.

First, create a `List` to serve as the available options. It's best to do this in your controller and pass it to your GSP via the model. Your list can consist of key/value pairs like this:

```
def options = [
    [id: 0, desc: 'Casual'], 
    [id: 1, desc: 'Serious'],
    [id: 2, desc: 'Very Serious']
]
```

Next, in your GSP you can use something like this:

```
<g:select 
    name="sereousness" 
    from="${options}"
    value="${subscribed.sereousness}"
    optionKey="id"
    optionValue="desc"
    noSelection="['':'-Choose your seriousness-']"/>
```

The `<g:select>` tag will generate an options list containing the items in `options`. The selected item will be the one identified in `subscribed.sereousness`. When an item is selected and the form is submitted the value of `sereousness` will contain the value (ID) of the selected option.